# I want to put a bounty on my question but I can only add +100

Tags: support, bounty

This is because I added an answer, realized it wasn't actually working and deleted the answer. But anyone with an answer posted must offer up 100 rep as a bounty (which is more than I want to offer).

Is there any other process other than re-asking the question (which I do not want to do) so I can offer a +50 bounty?

Edit: It seems someone has offered the bounty for me, which I am very grateful for. Thank you very much. The question in question is here: [Why is TopShelf not logging until the service is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746454/why-is-topshelf-not-logging-until-the-service-is-restarted)

I suppose the question remains, is there a way to revert the question to a state where a +50 rep bounty can be added after adding an answer yourself?

Comment: Can you link to the question? If it's a good one, it may get the required exposure (or someone may be kind enough to put up the bounty for you). If not, be prepared for downvotes.

Comment: @jpp not exactly a win-win situation, right?

Comment: @rene, Of course. But if it's a good question, it's a risk worth taking, no? I'd certainly put up the bounty if I genuinely thought it was a good question.

Comment: @jpp you and I can probably handle the responsibility. Let's see what the rest of the meta crowd will do ...

Comment: @rene This part of the meta crowd is preparing to grab some popcorn and just see what happens :)

Comment: If I'm thinking out of the box you could request dissociation from the deleted answer so you no longer have an answer on that question. I doubt if this has ever been done / tested so it might still not work. On top of that dissociation is only possible by using the contact us form and if they find your post deleted I wonder if SE staff is willing to honor your request in that case. Keep in mind that deleting questions that already have other answers is heavily frowned upon, specially if you re-post later.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746454/why-is-topshelf-not-logging-until-the-service-is-restarted) of yours has just received a bounty, is it this one?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty whoever did that. I suppose that solves the issue. Yes, that was the correct question @WhatsThePoint

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add 50 bounty to a question you have an answer on. This was because it was possible to [cheat the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack) by adding a small 50 bounty to a question, and then answering it really well. The bounty will attract lots of attention to your really good answer which will garner lots of upvotes, 10 reputation each, for the price of 50 bounty. All this attention brought by your own bounty allows 5 upvotes to already pay off the price of your bounty. So, in attempt to prevent this, the minimum bounty on a question you have answered is 100.

So, regarding your issue, really you cannot do anything to be able to add this 50 bounty (besides re-asking), unless someone else happens to offer the bounty to the question (which seems to already have happened!).

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame because I had deleted the answer so it's not even like I could 'cheat the system' in this instance.

Comment: @JamieTwells it is possible to *undelete* an answer too...